# Adding a title to chart, can´t find the title element

Tags: vb.net, charts, mschart

Can't find my title element to the chart even do I add title to the chart.

```
   Imports System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting
With chartResult
Dim t As Title = .Titles.Add("title1")
.Titles("title1").Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft 'This is saying it can´t
can´t find the title 
end With
```

Argumentexception unhandle by user code
A chart element with the name 'title1' could not be found in the 'TitleCollection'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim t As Title = chartResult.Titles.Add("Title1")
    t.Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearing titles (all):

```
 Chart1.Titles.Clear()
```

Adding title(s):

```
 Chart1.Titles.Add("some string")
```

Reading title from chart (first):

```
dim s As String = Chart1.Titles.Item(0).Text
```